# Reordering a list in python according to the changes made in another

Tags: python

I have two lists A and B of the same size. The first list is made of tuples. I reorder this first list A using the lambda function (so that I order according to the first element of the tuple). Is there a way to reorder the second list according to the same changes? That is, if the third element of list A is moved to place 7, then so does the third element in list B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [(1,'a'), (3,'b'), (2,'c')]
b = [4,6,5]

sort_function = lambda x: x[0][0]
sort_target = list(zip(a,b))
sort_target.sort(key = sort_function)

resorted_a, resorted_b = zip(*sort_target)

print (resorted_a) # prints ((1, 'a'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'b'))
print (resorted_b) # prints (4, 5, 6)
```

You'll have to slightly modify you current sorting lambda function. In short, it should treat it's argument as tuple that have two items: item from first list and item from second list. So, to preserve sorting order you should first extract first element from tuple, than apply your current sorting lambda.

`resorted_a` and `resorted_b` come out as tuples, but I hope that's not a problem (otherwise explicitly turn them to list, e.g. `list_a = list(resorted_a)`)

Refer to python documentation on [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for details. Note it's stated in official documentation:

> zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list:

Comment: @JOHN The unpacking into two lists using zip is excellent trick. You made my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code right now looks probably like this:

```
A.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Following @J0HN s suggestion:

```
A,B = zip(*sorted(zip(x,y),key=lambda x:x[0][0]))
```

will sort both lists according to the first element of the tupels in A.

Answer (score 1):

Following the zip, sort, unpack idea:

```
lstA = ["a", "b", "z", "d"]
lstB = ["1a", "2b", "3z", "4d"]
print "lstA", lstA
print "lstB", lstB

# willing to have lstA sorted alphabetically and order of items in lstB follow the changes

sumlst = zip(lstA, lstB)
sumlst.sort(key=lambda itm: itm[0])

print "sumlst", sumlst

#unpack it to two separate lists

lstA = [a for a, b in sumlst]
lstB = [b for a, b in sumlst]

print "lstA", lstA
print "lstB", lstB
```

with output:

```
lstA ['a', 'b', 'z', 'd']
lstB ['1a', '2b', '3z', '4d']
sumlst [('a', '1a'), ('b', '2b'), ('d', '4d'), ('z', '3z')]
lstA ['a', 'b', 'd', 'z']
lstB ['1a', '2b', '4d', '3z']
```